# Getter and Setter Function Help and How To

Tags: java, function, setter, getter

I am currently writing a program in which I need to incorporate get functions to produce and output for the program. The program needs to have Number of SeatsA = 30 and the pricePerSeatA = 120.99. I thought the way my program was set up all i would need to do is call these functions and then set the amount and then print. I've tried using ConcertSales concertSales= new ConcertSales(); but anytime I get ready to call the function I use concertSales.getNumberOfSeatsTypeA(); or concertSales.setNumberOfSeatsTypeA(30) and it gives me an error message. What am I doing wrong? Please help! Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
class ConcertSales{
ConcertSales concertSales = new ConcertSales();
public int numberOfSeatTypesA;
public int numberOfSeatTypesB;
public double pricePerSeatA;
public double pricePerSeatB;
public double totalSales; 

public int getNumberOfSeatTypesA()
{ return numberOfSeatTypesA;}
//did the same for Types B

public void setNumberOfSeatTypesA(int newValue) 
 { numberOfSeatTypesA = newValue; }
//same done for SeatsB

public double computeTotalSales()
{ return totalSales = numberOfSeatTypesA*pricePerSeatA +
                       numberOfSeatTypesB*pricePerSeatB }
}
concertSales.setNumberOfSeatTypesA(30); //this is where i keep getting 
my error messages.
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: Ironically for this site, it likely states `StackOverflowException`. You're creating a ConcertSales object inside of your ConcertSales class, and will thus be creating another ConcertSales object inside of that ConcertSales object, and this will keep on going recursively until you run out of memory. You don't want to do this. You also want to ask a more informative better question, one that shows us your error messages and all pertinent details.

Comment: This is truly amazing.

Comment: Here is what the error code says: Uncompilable source code - non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are a Java beginner, or a OOP beginner. In Java, all functions/methods should be insides of a class, even main function.

Here is the code:

```
class ConcertSales{
    public int numberOfSeatTypesA;
    public int numberOfSeatTypesB;
    public double pricePerSeatA;
    public double pricePerSeatB;
    public double totalSales; 

    public int getNumberOfSeatTypesA(){ 
        return numberOfSeatTypesA;
    }

    public void setNumberOfSeatTypesA(int newValue){ 
        numberOfSeatTypesA = newValue; 
    }

    public double computeTotalSales(){ 
        return totalSales = numberOfSeatTypesA*pricePerSeatA +
                   numberOfSeatTypesB*pricePerSeatB;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConcertSales concertSales = new ConcertSales();
        concertSales.setNumberOfSeatTypesA(30); 
        System.out.println(concertSales.getNumberOfSeatTypesA());
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is what the error code says: Uncompilable source code - non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: I just tested the code, and I got no error. Did you try my code with modifications? If does, what are the modifications? I don't try to access any non-static variable in static method (except the main function).

Comment: Chong it worked now. I made the mistake of starting the class under the main. This helped. Thank you for your help and actually  being nice about it.

Answer (score 0):

did you write your class into the main method ?

it's the other way around, your class contains a main method

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. You don't need ConcertSales concertSales = new ConcertSales(); since Java will automatically construct the default constructor. That line should be moved into your main program.
2. You should move your ConcertSales Class outside of main. Preferably in another file.
3. Assuming you created a separate class for ConcertSales your main class would look as follows.

   `public static void main(String[] args) { 
   ConcertSales sales = new ConcertSales(); // create new ConcertSales object
   sales.setNumberOfSeatTypesA(30);
   }`

Comment: Thank you Jon A. I got it all figured out. I put my class inside of main which was my problem. Stupid beginner mistake